# pic18f communicating with lcd module

Tags: assembly, pic18, mikroc

I'm developing on a pic 18Fxxx (18F452) in assembly. I'm in a learning phase so I'm doing different simple exercise with the final goal to develop a "real" project.

At the moment I'm stuck with the LCD Module, I couldn't find any examples of a working protocol to comunicate with the screen (on 4 bit). Can someone please link me some code or a to-be-implemented procedure from which I can understand how all this works?

Thank you.

note: My IDE is [MPLAB](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en019469&part=SW007002) and I'm using [PIC18 Simulator IDE](http://www.oshonsoft.com/pic18.html) to check how my code works.

Comment: A suggestion. Make this question in the Electronics & Robotics site: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at these links, they cover the topics of LCD, PIC and ASM at diferent levels:

- http://www.spickles.org/projects/4-bit-lcd
- http://home.iae.nl/users/pouweha/lcd/lcd.shtml
- http://www.winpicprog.co.uk/pic_tutorial.htm

As well I would like to recommend you to move on to C (if you don't need the ASM for something specific). Now it's common to develop for the PIC in C, the compilers are nice and the code is fast, you can learn the ASM and leave it for some "important" routines like interrupt handlers. After if you move to the 16bit or even 32bit pics the C will be a must.

I use the [MikroC](http://www.mikroe.com/eng/home/index/) compiler for PIC from Mikroelektronica and it is working very well. You can find too free tools for C development. As a last point I recommend you to move on to the pic [18F4520](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010297), is pin comaptible with the 18F452 but is newer and powerfuller. (the 452 is discontinued i think)